# VMware vSphere / ESXi 5.5 recommended guest system architecture

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, 32-vs-64-bit, vsphere, esxi5.5

I am currently setting um VMware vSphere / ESXi 5.5 on a DellPowerEdge2900 and since it's an older server the following question came to my mind:

Considering performance should I install guest systems as 32bit or 64bit versions?
Or doesn't it make any difference at all?

Comment: +0 because it doesn't belong here. This question is too old to migrate, but in the future, please post such questions on our sister site [serverfault.com](//www.serverfault.com/) instead. You'll probably get more and better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the 32/64-bit OS versions required by your applications. Your 2900 will run either just fine. Specifically use 64-bit OSes where you need more than 4GB of virtual machine memory.